# source nsis setup have virus

Tags: exe, nsis

I Have nsis source setup ajax file and clean the internet explorer becose sameone use file dll to block me

the file when i go to virustotal i get to virus i don't know where the problem can anyone help me

this is the source

```
; saudivoice NSIS Installer Script File
; khaild Winston <babh532@gmail.com>
;--------------------------------
;Include some predefined NSIS libraries

  !include "WinMessages.nsh"

; --------------------
XPStyle on


; LANG: 1033
LangString LSTR_43 1033 "Show &details"
LangString LSTR_44 1033 Completed
; --------------------
;General

  ;Name and file
  Name "SaudiVoice"

  ;Default installation folder
  InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILES\SaudiVoice"

; --------------------
; PAGES: 3

; Page 0
Page license /ENABLECANCEL
  LicenseText "Welcome to the Saudivoice Voice Setup." Next
  LicenseData [LICENSE].txt

; Page 1
Page instfiles
  CompletedText $(LSTR_44)    ;  Completed
  DetailsButtonText $(LSTR_43)    ;  "Show &details"

/*
; Page 2
Page COMPLETED
*/
; --------------------


; --------------------
; SECTIONS: 1

;Installer Sections

Section "Install saudivoice" 

  SetOutPath "$INSTDIR"

  ; Copy all of the required files (note the /r switch to recursively copy                     directories)
    File chat5.ocx
    File chat5.dll
    File chat5.inf
    File setup.bat
    File IMSVoiceStarter.exe
    File npIMSChatStarter.dll
    File Readme.htm
    ; Register the COM server
    ClearErrors
    RegDLL $INSTDIR\chat5.ocx
    RegDLL $INSTDIR\npIMSChatStarter.dll
    Exec $INSTDIR\setup.bat
    Exec "$PROGRAMFILES\KSAChatControl2017\Firewall\Uninstall.exe /S"
    DetailPrint "unInstalling the Block..."
    Exec "$PROGRAMFILES\KSAChatControl2017\Firewall14\Uninstall.exe /S"
    DetailPrint "unInstalling the Block..."
    Exec "$PROGRAMFILES\KSAChatControl2017\2.11.0.0\Uninstall.exe /S"
    DetailPrint "unInstalling the Block..."
    CreateDirectory $SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice\Read Me.lnk" $INSTDIR\Readme.htm
    CreateShortCut "$SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice\Uninstall SaudiVoice.lnk"             $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe
    WriteRegStr HKLM       Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice DisplayName       "SaudiVoice 1.0.0.1"
    WriteRegStr HKLM       Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice DisplayVersion 1.0.0.1
    WriteRegStr HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice UninstallString $\"$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe$\"
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice NoModify 1
    DeleteRegKey HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice
    WriteRegDWORD HKLM Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice NoRepair 1
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Code Store Database\Distribution Units\{EB938183-780F-48FD-89ED-50686F7F7259}"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ModuleUsage"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Code Store Database\Distribution Units\{EB938183-780F-48FD-89ED-50686F7F7259}"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ModuleUsage"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\SharedDlls"
    DeleteRegKey HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains"
    DeleteRegKey HKCU "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges"
    DeleteRegKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Ranges"
    DeleteRegKey HKEY_USERS ".DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows Firewall"
    WriteUninstaller $INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe ;  $INSTDIR\$INSTDIR\Uninst.exe
  SectionEnd



  ; --------------------
  ;Uninstaller Section

  Section "Uninstall"

    Delete "$INSTDIR\Uninstall.exe"

    ; Unregister the COM server
    UnRegDLL "$INSTDIR\chat5.ocx"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\chat5.ocx"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\chat5.dll"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\chat5.inf"
          Delete "$INSTDIR\IMSVoiceStarter.exe"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\npIMSChatStarter.dll"
    Delete "$INSTDIR\Readme.htm"
    ; Delete all installed files
    RMDir "$INSTDIR"

    ; And registry entries
    DeleteRegKey HKLM       "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\SaudiVoice"
    Delete "$SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice\Read Me.lnk"
    Delete  "$SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice\Uninstall SaudiVoice.lnk"
    RMDir $SMPROGRAMS\SaudiVoice

  SectionEnd
```

and this is the file

```
 http://saudidos.com/fix.exe
```

Please help me for that

Comment: This is a false positive alarm, please report it.

Answer (score 1):

The VirusTotal [results](https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/e1b45a29be0ffd6127b227eb5be8658ad1b96efbe3b722b89ac04b9af922193f/analysis/) have a detection ratio of 2 / 55 and the two are Bkav and Invincea and I would go out on a limb and say that these are not well known companies and this is probably a false positive. You could try [reporting](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/how-report-malware-or-false-positives-multiple-antivirus-vendors.htm) the false positives...

Answer (score 0):

This isn't the [first time](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSIS_False_Positives) this happened to nsis or some related [plugins](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=Version_plug-in&oldid=23236). Just inform those companies or [virustotal](https://www.virustotal.com/de/about/privacy/) (chapter "Information we share") will also do that for you (which only may take a while longer)...