# How to make minimal setup.exe good for virustotal?

Tags: c, winapi

I have some setup.exe based on NSIS. It setup.exe installs plugin. Setup.exe does some simple actions: allow user to choose application folder then registry and some files on filesystem then copy plugin file in some user folder. My problem: virustotal shows some warnings but plugin is good. Plugin file upload to virustotal doesn't show any warnings.

So I want to replace NSIS with something else. Currently I think to write own setup.exe on WinAPI  without any extra tools/libraries. But doesn't know how to mix setup.exe with actual data files which must copied? Or maybe there is another way to make setup.exe good for Virustotal?

Comment: Have you tried naming your installer something other than *"setup.exe"*? An application with that name is treated differently by the OS (see [Why didn't Windows XP auto-elevate programs beyond those named setup.exe?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100726-00/?p=13323)).

Comment: @IInspectable if I well understand the problem is about the fact https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home detect problem(s) (virus, troyen etc) on the setup of the OP

Comment: In the long list of detectors used by virustotal very few of them signal false positive, and generally this is always the same detector(s). For my tool I often have something signaled my CMC ( https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/aa4b9cda5832eaa341aedfb6f5f7e56482aa429b955b46782c294cdbe9328c43/detection ) but it is the alone among 70 detectors, and CMC is known to produce false positive. If you have several detectors signaling the same problem take care, else do not

Comment: IInspectable, I renamed installer to aaa.exe and still see warnings in Virustotal.

Comment: What kind of warning?

Comment: @crea7or  file infected by some viruses.

Comment: This may be a false positive alarm. Refer: [source nsis setup have virus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40309123/source-nsis-setup-have-virus)

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT definitely it is a false positive alarm. I know it but anyway I need to avoid them.

Comment: @IvanRomanov Some cases show that the most direct way is to report the false positives.

Comment: Before you invest time and effort into writing your own setup program try [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to create the installer. I have uploaded some installation programs that use InnoSetup and VirusTotal did not complain.

Comment: @OlafHess no success.

Comment: Are you ready to try to use winapi to write your own setup.exe？

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT actually I've allready done this but still have some Virustotal warnings.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple options available for creating installers and outlined by Microsoft in their [application deployment guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/deploying-applications-services-and-components?view=vs-2019#create-an-installer-package-windows-desktop).  You can use ClickOnce, InstallShield, MSI or MSIX.

If the false positives don't go away and 1-2 false positives are unacceptable to you, then you should get a code signing certificate and sign your installer.  If the false positives don't go away you need to contact the antivirus vendors and report the false positive.